# Electrical Connection AprilAire 600M Bypass Humidifier

Tags: electrical, hvac, humidifier

I have a 2-stage furnace and I want to connect the 24VAC from the humidifier to the thermostat connections on the control board.  Since the control board has W1 and W2 connectors, which one should I use in conjunction with the C so the humidifier operates when the blower runs?

[image: Electrical wiring schematic]

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for your furnace, as well as photos of the control board?

Comment: Wiring schematic posted.  I can send a PDF version (couldn't figure how to post) if needed.

Comment: Can you post a link to a PDF version of the manual -- or just the make/model number for that matter -- in a comment?

Comment: Model # FG7TA    Finding the manual online is a challenge.

Comment: Make is Westinghouse

Comment: PS: I tested C to Y on the thermostat panel and got 24 VAC since the AC is running.  This is the voltage I need for the humidifier.  It seems to just be a question of W1 or W2 on the pannel

Comment: Here is a link to the manual:  709045-A G7TA-K 80 two-stage Furn ii.indd

Comment: http://enora.nortekhvac.com/literature/709045a.pdf

Comment: Can you measure from the HUM terminal on your board to ground when the heat is running?

Comment: The HUM terminal is 120V.  I think I could use the HUM terminal with the 24VAC transformer supplied by AprilAire.  Or use the C & W1 on the thermostat connection.

Comment: Richard, please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what's expected of you when you ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

### W1 should work

If you want the humidifier running whenever the heat's running, then using the W1 and C terminals on the thermostat connection should indeed work.

### ...but, I'd make sure there's a humidistat on this

However, I would make sure there's a humidistat controlling the humidifier (it can simply be in series between W1 and the humidifier, provided it's an open-on-rise/close-on-fall type) as well, as too much humidity is a rather effective way to slow-kill a house.

Comment: Thank You - and, yes, there is a humidistat controlling the process.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you have a 2 stage furnace is less important in regards to your humidifier then if you have a 2 stage thermostat. The W1 are W2 terminals on the furnace are input only. They wait for a 24v signal. So if you have a single stage thermostat connected to W1 the furnace will kick in to 2nd stage after a pre-determined amount of time. Connecting to W1 would apply here. With a 2 stage thermostat the W1 contact is usually maintained during a call for second stage heat by the thermostat, so connecting to W1 still applies here. Sometimes I've run into a 2 stage with only a W2 connection at the furnace. Making it an expensive single stage furnace. In that odd case connecting it to W2 is the appropriate action. Or you could just wire the transformer into the HUM terminal.